# Reading bluetooth data and sending obtained message to UI (Android & C#)

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth

My app must get data from a bluetooth barcode reader. The string data should be sent directly to the virtual keyboard input (or EditText field).

I'm a C# guy and I work on Xamarin Studio. But all of the code examples about Android are in Java. So usually I need to convert the code snippets to implement them into my app.

The most reliable code about bluetooth interaction is [the official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html). So I'm converting that.

Also I examined and took some line of codes from the [Bluetooth Chat example in C#](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/BluetoothChat). But it's just too complicated and broad.

I somehow managed to pair and connect the device, I got the input stream data. And to read it, this is the method I made:

```
public void BTOku(Stream veri) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytes;
    while (true) {
        try {
            bytes = veri.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) buffer;
            var readMessage = new Java.Lang.String (readBuf, 0, bytes);
            //Console.WriteLine (readMessage);
        } catch {
            //break;
        }
    }
}
```

I run this method on a new thread as suggested. "readMessage" is the string I want to send directly to keyboard and/or to the focused EditText.

1. How can I do this?
2. Did I strip the code too much? Am I doing this right?
3. I probably need to use custom handlers (and ObtainMessage method)
   but I'm really confused about using those outside of the basic UI
   events.